# Прятать viewpager при появлении клавиатуры

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, android-viewpager

У меня есть View Pager, который находится внизу  и занимает примерно треть экрана. Мне нужно, чтобы он убирался при появлении клавиатуры и снова появлялся, когда она убирается. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал такой способ:

[image: ezgif-com-gif-maker.gif]

`Kotlin`:

```
root_layout.viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener {
    val rect = Rect()
    root_layout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect)
    val heightDiff = root_layout.rootView.height - (rect.bottom - rect.top)
    button.visibility = if (heightDiff > 200) GONE else VISIBLE
}
```

`Java`:

```
final View rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
final View button = findViewById(R.id.button);

rootLayout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(() -> {
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    rootLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
    int heightDiff = rootLayout.getRootView().getHeight() - (rect.bottom - rect.top);
    if (heightDiff > 200) {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Только в вашем случае у вас будет меняться видимость `ViewPager`

`root_layout` это корневой лэйаут вашего макета